# state.animateScrollToItem() is not working in LazyColumn

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, lazycolumn

`I am trying to animate LazyColumn items with state.animateScrollItems() function. But is not not working. It is working very well with state.scrollItmes() function.

I am using compose_ui_verdion 1.2.1, compose_compiler_version 1.3.2 and kotlin version 1.7.20

```
LazyColumn(
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    state = state
) {
    item {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(Color(color = 0x93F1ECEC)),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Enter purchase details :",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(vertical = 4.dp, horizontal = 4.dp),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.error
            )
        }

    }

    item {
        FirstThreeRows {

        }
    }
    item {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
   }
    item {
        ProductListTitle()
    }
    item {
        ProductList() //  it is another lazycolumn
    }
    item {
        ItemSelectionRows { focused ->
            Log.i(TAG, "HomeScreen2: $focused")
            if (focused) {

                coroutineScope.launch {
                    state.animateScrollToItem(2)

                }
            } else {
                coroutineScope.launch {
                    state.animateScrollToItem(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    item {
        ProductButtonRow()
    }
    item {
        ProductPriceColumn()
    }
    item { 
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    }
    item {
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = "Submit")
        }
    }
    item {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(300.dp))
    }
}
```

Please give me a solution.`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change `state` to `listState` to distinguish with parameter

> val listState = rememberLazyListState()

Comment: Changed as per the opinion val listState = rememberLazyListState(). But result is same